# Background Application without service

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have developed an Android application with Delphi Berlin. It works fine.
I want to know, without making changes, how make the application not killed by the OS when I run another application on the phone.
I want to avoid the solution of services.

Comment: Android is a multitasking OS, it can run multiple apps at a time. Simply starting another app will not kill your app right away (but it may get paused). You must handle the [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) correctly. The OS won't kill your app unless it needs to free up resources for other tasks. "*without making changes*" - then what you are asking for can't be done. You are going to have to make SOME change somewhere. "*I want to avoid the solution of services*" - why? Background processing is what a service is meant for.

Comment: Sorry, It is not clear for me. Multitasking OS and starting another app do not kill the app. So why I must make some change. I want to have the app to continue to run even if I start another app. As a messenger who continues to receive messages even if you have moved to another app.
I have my application that regularly receives data from a MYSQL server and I want it to continue doing it even if I use another application or when it is in the background. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It *is* clear. **Background processing is what a service is for.** If you want background processing, your app needs to be a service. Whether you want to avoid it or not doesn't matter, because it's what you need to do.

Comment: I thought that the two comments from @RemyLebeau and KenWhite together form a suitable answer to the question, so I wrote it. If any of you want to write your own answer, feel free to do so and I will delete mine.

Comment: Thank you for you helps. Just one last question. Is there a method to keep my application (whitch work fine) as it is and make a minimal change to have a background application? I never work on serices or backrgound apps.

Answer (score 4):

Android is a multitasking OS, it can run multiple apps at a time. Simply starting another app will not kill your app right away (but it may get paused). You must handle the Activity Lifecycle correctly. The OS won't kill your app unless it needs to free up resources for other tasks.

**without making changes** - then what you are asking for can't be done. You are going to have to make SOME change somewhere.

**I want to avoid the solution of services** - Background processing is what a service is meant for. If you want background processing, your app needs to be a service.